# Spark PushedFilters

Tags: apache-spark

When you do `df.explain()` it is possible to see in the Physical plan the `PushedFilters` for predicate pushdown as a string. This we can extract with `df.queryExecution.simpleString` but I want it as JSON so I can directly test whether something was put in PushedFilters, how do I extract this?

e.g. from jacek laswoski's [website](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/spark-sql-Optimizer-PushDownPredicate.html) an example

```
cities.where('name === "Warsaw").queryExecution.executedPlan
res21: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan =
*Project [id#128L, name#129]
+- *Filter (isnotnull(name#129) && (name#129 = Warsaw))
   +- *FileScan parquet [id#128L,name#129] Batched: true, 
Format: ParquetFormat, 
InputPaths: file:/Users/jacek/dev/oss/spark/cities.parquet, 
PartitionFilters: [], 
PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(name), EqualTo(name,Warsaw)], 
ReadSchema: struct<id:bigint,name:string>
```

i want to be able to extract the `PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(name), EqualTo(name,Warsaw)]` for some testing I'm doing

Comment: If you want JSON, parse the string, unless the plan object has a getter for that information

Comment: yeah i was basically hoping there was a getter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out

```
df.queryExecution.sparkPlan.collectFirst{case p : FileSourceScanExec => p}.get.metadata("PushedFilters")
```